# Database connection pool[Hikari] initialize error

Tags: java, web-applications, database-connection, connection-pooling, hikaricp

I am trying to configure HikariCP for my web application. I am not using any frameworks, it is a plain simple java web app. When I tried to establish a connection through normal JDBC it was successful and I was able to perform all database operations.

However, when I am trying to get a connection with a connection pool, I get an exception after initialization which I have no clue about.

Below is the config that I am using, I am initializing it in a context listener. I am running on Java 1.7, with a Tomcat container using HikariCP Java 6 dependency 2.3.2

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;
import com.mkgcorp.travelweb.util.TLog;
import com.sun.jersey.core.util.Base64;
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig;
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource;

public class CPInit implements ServletContextListener{

    private final static String TAG = CPInit.class.getSimpleName();
    private static HikariConfig mConfig;
    private static HikariDataSource mDataSource;

    public static String POOL_NAME = "TripPool";
    public static int POOL_SIZE = 10;
    public static int TIME_OUT = 30*1000;
    public static int MIN_IDLE_SIZE = 2;
    public static boolean isDebuggable;

    private String PASSWORD = "YWRtaW4=";


    public CPInit(){
        String string = new String(Base64.decode(PASSWORD));
        TLog.info(TAG, "Password = " + string);
        mConfig = new HikariConfig();
        mConfig.setDataSourceClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource");
        mConfig.addDataSourceProperty("url", "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/travlemate");
        mConfig.addDataSourceProperty("cachePrepStmts", "true");
        mConfig.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSize", "250");
        mConfig.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", "2048");
        mConfig.addDataSourceProperty("useServerPrepStmts", "true");
        mConfig.addDataSourceProperty("user", "root");
        mConfig.addDataSourceProperty("password", string);
        mConfig.setMaximumPoolSize(POOL_SIZE);
        mConfig.setMinimumIdle(MIN_IDLE_SIZE);
        mConfig.setPoolName(POOL_NAME);
        mConfig.setConnectionTimeout(TIME_OUT);
        mConfig.setAutoCommit(true);
        mConfig.setInitializationFailFast(false);
        mDataSource = new HikariDataSource(mConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        TLog.info(TAG, "CP has being destroyed");
        mDataSource.close();

    }

    public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException{
        TLog.info(TAG, "get data connection");
        return mDataSource.getConnection();
    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        TLog.info(TAG, "CP has been initilizing");
        String parm = arg0.getServletContext().getInitParameter("debugging");
        isDebuggable = Boolean.valueOf(parm);
    }

}
```

This is the exception that I am getting:

```
java.sql.SQLTimeoutException: Timeout after 30005ms of waiting for a connection.
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool.getConnection(BaseHikariPool.java:228)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool.getConnection(BaseHikariPool.java:183)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:91)
    at com.mkgcorp.travelweb.controller.CPInit.getConnection(CPInit.java:68)
    at com.mkgcorp.travelweb.data.Database.getConnection(Database.java:47)
    at com.mkgcorp.travelweb.data.DataManager.getConnection(DataManager.java:100)
    at com.mkgcorp.travelweb.data.DataManager.authenticateUser(DataManager.java:135)
    at com.mkgcorp.travelweb.webservices.TripResource.isUserValid(TripResource.java:169)
    at com.mkgcorp.travelweb.webservices.SyncResource.getContactStatus(SyncResource.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:540)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:715)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:71)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1556)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1513)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: JDBC4 Connection.isValid() method not supported, connection test query must be configured
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool.addConnection(BaseHikariPool.java:399)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$1AddConnection.run(HikariPool.java:78)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually I got the answer, Hikari needs to set a connection test query, if thats done JDBC4 isValid will not get called.

so just by adding property, I was able to make it work.

```
mConfig.setConnectionTestQuery("show tables");
```

Comment: As a special note, MySQL supports a query: "/* ping */".  It is more efficient.  See this page: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-usagenotes-tomcat.html search for the word "ping".

Comment: Also note that MySQL Connector/J from 5.1.6+ supports isValid(), so if you upgrade your driver you should be able to remove the validation query.

Comment: Thanks for response @brettw, I Will use ping query, certainly I will look into getting my driver upgraded to get rid of test query altogether.

Comment: @brettw am facing an strange issue now, am getting ava.sql.SQLTimeoutException: Timeout after 30003ms of waiting for a connection.
 at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool.getConnection(BaseHikariPool.java:228)

Comment: am performing an db operation in loop, at start call getConnection, and once my operation is complete i simply call conn.close(), its working for first few loops but in between its failing to provide connection and my program is crashing. any idea ?

Comment: can you open an issue over on github?  It's easier to hold a discussion, post your configuration, etc.  At a minimum, enable debug logging, it may shed some light on what is happening.

Answer (score 4):

I was hitting the same problem, and I just figured it out.

I'm on a Mac, and somehow I had `postgresql-9.0-802.jdbc3.jar` installed in my `/Library/Java/Extensions` directory. `DriverManager` would pick this up as the preferred way of connecting to a `jdbc:posgresql://` URL. It's a JDBC3 driver, so there's no `isValid` method.

Even when I put a JDBC4 Driver on my classpath, whether that was `org.prosgreql.Driver` or `com.impossibl.postgres.jdbc.PGDriver`, the JDBC3 driver would supersede it.

So I deleted `/Library/Java/Extensions/postgresql*` and all is well.