# Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: JDBC4 Connection.isValid() method not supported

Tags: scala, heroku, heroku-postgres, playframework-2.4, slick-3.0

My play-framework project is running well in my local but when I am trying to deploy it in heroku I am getting following error.

```
2015-07-05T06:24:10.456657+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:73)
2015-07-05T06:24:10.456817+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder.build(GuiceApplicationBuilder.scala:93)
2015-07-05T06:24:10.456702+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62)
2015-07-05T06:24:10.456746+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceBuilder.injector(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:126)
2015-07-05T06:24:10.456863+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationLoader.load(GuiceApplicationLoader.scala:21)
2015-07-05T06:24:10.456909+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.start(ProdServerStart.scala:52)
2015-07-05T06:24:10.456951+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.main(ProdServerStart.scala:27)
2015-07-05T06:24:10.456994+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.core.server.ProdServerStart.main(ProdServerStart.scala)
2015-07-05T06:24:10.457407+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool.addConnection(BaseHikariPool.java:441)
2015-07-05T06:24:10.457496+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
2015-07-05T06:24:10.457369+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: JDBC4 Connection.isValid() method not supported, connection test query must be configured
2015-07-05T06:24:10.457602+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
2015-07-05T06:24:10.457451+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool$1.run(BaseHikariPool.java:413)
2015-07-05T06:24:10.457681+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
2015-07-05T06:24:10.457812+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2015-07-05T06:24:10.457768+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
2015-07-05T06:24:11.231007+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 255
2015-07-05T06:24:11.243795+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-07-05T06:24:11.245013+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-07-05T06:24:16.259302+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `target/universal/stage/bin/sazors -Dhttp.port=10803`
2015-07-05T06:24:17.542815+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx384m -Xss512k -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
2015-07-05T06:24:18.643391+00:00 app[web.1]: 06:24:18,391 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
2015-07-05T06:24:18.643397+00:00 app[web.1]: 06:24:18,391 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
```

I am using PostgreSQL as my db and slick as database access library. I tried to google it and after some research I found out this error can be caused when provided url in configuration file is incorrect or it is returning null. I tried to fix it but I couldn't resolve this error.

Here is my Procfile:

> web: target/universal/stage/bin/myapp -Dhttp.port=${PORT} -Dconfig.resource=${PLAY_CONF_FILE}

and Application.conf

```
slick.dbs.default.driver="slick.driver.PostgresDriver$"
slick.dbs.default.db.driver="org.postgresql.Driver"
slick.dbs.default.db.url="postgres://rycmvicwkkzofh:Xt2PWggm__FQEHOeq9EoMqTOtF@ec2-54-243-132-114.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/d5pr4h65obtb0s"
slick.dbs.default.db.user=rycmuicwkkzofh
slick.dbs.default.db.password="copiedfromheroku"
```

P.S: I am working on these revisions

`play framework version : 2.4.0
 slick version : 3.0`

**EDIT**: If I add `slick.dbs.default.db.connectionTestQuery="SELECT 1"` in my application.conf it produces new type of nullPointerException Error.

```
That is gone but getting new error now:
2015-07-05T12:22:49.781133+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:73)
2015-07-05T12:22:49.781201+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62)
2015-07-05T12:22:49.781283+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceBuilder.injector(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:126)
2015-07-05T12:22:49.781361+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder.build(GuiceApplicationBuilder.scala:93)
2015-07-05T12:22:49.781507+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.start(ProdServerStart.scala:52)
2015-07-05T12:22:49.781425+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationLoader.load(GuiceApplicationLoader.scala:21)
2015-07-05T12:22:49.781599+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.main(ProdServerStart.scala:27)
2015-07-05T12:22:49.781669+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.core.server.ProdServerStart.main(ProdServerStart.scala)
2015-07-05T12:22:49.782161+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
2015-07-05T12:22:49.782226+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool.addConnection(BaseHikariPool.java:446)
2015-07-05T12:22:49.782328+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool$1.run(BaseHikariPool.java:413)
2015-07-05T12:22:49.782417+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
2015-07-05T12:22:49.782515+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
2015-07-05T12:22:49.783691+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
2015-07-05T12:22:49.783803+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
2015-07-05T12:22:49.783883+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: See if you can specify a cheap test query on the connection, e.g. `SELECT 1`. The property will be called something like `connectionTestQuery`. [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28391936/database-connection-poolhikari-initialize-error) and [here](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/issues/225)

Comment: @StuartLC: Could you please elaborate more, where do I need to specify this cheap test query?

Comment: Can you verify which version of postgresdriver you are using ? The latest ones should have fixed this.

Comment: In my local it is `pg_ctl (PostgreSQL) 9.3.5`, I checked in heroku it is using `PostgreSQL 9.4.4` and in my build.sbt I have added `"org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.4-1201-jdbc41"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this problem was discussed on [the Play mailing list here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/play-framework/heroku$20slick$20isValid/play-framework/nPomE1Z-xb8/gc2qqG8dxqwJ).

The cause turned out to be that Slick does not support the DATABASE_URL format that Heroku sets. You will have to parse the DATABASE_URL into a JDBC URL. You can do this fairly easily with the heroku-jdbc library:
https://github.com/jkutner/heroku-jdbc

Just add a line like this to your deps:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.heroku.sdk" % "heroku-jdbc" % "0.1.0"
```

Then you can parse the URL like so:

```
var jdbcURL = DatabaseUrl.extract.jdbcUrl
```

Then pass that URL to slick

**EDIT**

Actually, looks like most people are parsing the DATABASE_URL manually, and setting up slick conf with hard-coded values. This is fine, but be aware that the connection may change, and you'd have to change your settings manually.

So you'll need to change your config to this:

```
slick.dbs.default.db.url="jdbc:postgresql://host:port/path"
```

But you might want to destroy and recreate your database because you've posted your connection details in the public.

I've submitted a PR to slick to fix this:
https://github.com/slick/slick/pull/1193

Comment: Note that [heroku now provides a JDBC_DATABSE_URL](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-to-relational-databases-on-heroku-with-java#using-the-jdbc_database_url)

Answer (score 5):

The Play [HikariCP module](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play-jdbc/src/main/scala/play/api/db/HikariCPModule.scala#L123) (look for "connectionTestQuery" config) suggests that you can set the test query as follows:

```
slick.dbs.default.db.connectionTestQuery="/*ping*/ select 1" // or whatever
```

Then the error in your stacktrace should in theory go away.

Comment: I added that line but now getting nullPointerException. Please look into question description, I have updated question details with my new error.

Comment: Have you got the PostgreSQL database setup on Heroku? Is the app using the environment variable with the PostgreSQL URL in the Procfile? https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ProductionHeroku

Answer (score 1):

Play configuration requires jdbc url (JDBC_DATABASE_URL) and not postgres (DATABASE URL) to convert database url into jdbc url here is the way. Notice in the first line `postgres` is written in the next line which starts with jdbc `postgresql` `ql` is appended to the word `postgres`.

```
postgres://<username>:<password>@<host>:<port>/<dbname>
```

The above format is given heroku postgres. but play expects below format.

```
jdbc:postgresql://<host>:<port>/<dbname>?user=<username>&password=<password>
```

Note: In the above URL do not forget to add `ql` at the end `jdbc:postgres` + `ql` becomes `jdbc:postgresql`

Also add below line to play conf

```
slick.dbs.default.db.connectionTestQuery="SELECT 1"
```

Finally your configuration file `application.conf` becomes

```
slick.dbs.default.driver="slick.driver.PostgresDriver$"

slick.dbs.default.db.driver="org.postgresql.Driver"

slick.dbs.default.db.url="jdbc:postgresql://rycmvicwkkzofh:Xt2PWggm__FQEHOeq9EoMqTOtF@ec2-54-243-132-114.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/d5pr4h65obtb0s?user=rycmuicwkkzofh&password=copiedfromheroku"

slick.dbs.default.db.user=rycmuicwkkzofh

slick.dbs.default.db.password="copiedfromheroku"

slick.dbs.default.db.connectionTestQuery="SELECT 1"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and after upgrading to HikariCP-2.4.0 and Postgresql-9.4 the issue was resolved :)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
slick.dbs.default.driver="slick.driver.PostgresDriver$"
slick.dbs.default.db.dataSourceClass = "slick.jdbc.DatabaseUrlDataSource"
slick.dbs.default.db.driver="org.postgresql.Driver"
slick.dbs.default.db.url=${JDBC_DATABASE_URL}
```