# dataSourcePool close broken connection when release to pool

Tags: jdbc, connection-pooling, hikaricp

I'm use Hikari jdbc connection pool.

when execute statement witch produce an exception ( for example by network is broken). as following:

```
try{
   Connection con = pool.getConnection();
   con.executeQuery("....");
}catch(Exception e){
   con.close();
}
```

does `con.close` will evict the broken connection, instead of release it to the pool.

if the broken connection is released to pool. it maybe got by following request of `getConnection`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your driver is JDBC4 compatible (and supports `Connection.isValid()`) the validation of the connection is done via this API per default).

Otherwise you may set the [connectionTestQuery](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP) to be performed for the validation.

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28391936/database-connection-poolhikari-initialize-error) discussion and the [source](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/blob/dev/src/main/java/com/zaxxer/hikari/pool/PoolBase.java#L121) code.

Comment: in the source code, if lastAccess near than 1000ms, the alive check will not be done : https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/blob/dev/src/main/java/com/zaxxer/hikari/pool/HikariPool.java#L171

Comment: @Chinaxing a good observation, my interpretation is that this is performance optimization based on the assumption, that in a short idle time the connection will not get broken. This could be sensitive approach. Anyway the interval was [changed recently](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/commit/23c1b80bfd7ffa4df21365b6f5d6a80bcdc8f32d)

Answer (score 0):

Use con.close in finally block, otherwise in the catch block you must ask first if con != null for avoid the exception produced in the catch block. Other alernative could be enclose, con.close() in other try{}catch{} block. Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider try-with-resource:

```
try(Connection con = pool.getConnection()) {
  DO SOMETHING WITH CONNECTION
}catch(Exception e){
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

this will **guarantee** the connection is given back to the pool. Checking if a connection is valid is a task for the *pool*, not for *your code*. You can configure the pool to check your connection with the [connectionTestQuery](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP#configuration-knobs-baby) property - so there's that.

Comment: Not every Exception will break the Cinnection. So forcing reconnect on non fatal error will be more expensive.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using try-with-resource and if network is broken, HikariCP most likely will close connection, not recycle.
from HikariCP source, if there is such exception in connection.close(), it is closing connection in checkException()

Comment: the close function maybe not do network related task. so such exception maybe not threw, and the checkException will not be called. and the connection will be recycled to the pool

Comment: better write test case  that reproduces the behavior you imagine would be interesting.